# How to generate multi-dimensional 2D numpy index using a sub-index for one dimension

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I want to use `numpy.ix_` to generate an multi-dimensional index for a 2D space of values. However, I need to use a subindex to look up the indices for one dimension. For example,

```
    assert subindex.shape == (ny, nx)

    data = np.random.random(size=(ny,nx))

    # Generator returning the index tuples 
    def get_idx(ny,nx,subindex):
      for y in range(ny):
        for x in range(nx):
           yi = y             # This is easy
           xi = subindex[y,x] # Get the second index value from the subindex

           yield (yi,xi)

    # Generator returning the data values
    def get_data_vals(ny,nx,data,subindex):
      for y in range(ny):
        for x in range(nx):
           yi = y             # This is easy
           xi = subindex[y,x] # Get the second index value from the subindex

           yield data[y,subindex[y,x]]
```

So instead of the for loops above, I'd like to use a multi-dimensional index to index `data` Using `numpy.ix_`, I guess I would have something like:

```
    idx = numpy.ix_([np.arange(ny), ?])
    data[idx]
```

but I don't know what the second dimension argument should be. I'm guessing it should be something involving `numpy.choose`?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want here, can you provide an example?

Comment: Ashwini, I've updated the question a bit. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually seem to want is:

```
y_idx = np.arange(ny)[:,np.newaxis]
data[y_idx, subindex]
```

BTW, you could achieve the same thing with `y_idx = np.arange(ny).reshape((-1, 1))`.

Let's look at a small example:

```
import numpy as np
   
ny, nx = 3, 5
data = np.random.rand(ny, nx)
subindex = np.random.randint(nx, size=(ny, nx))
```

Now

```
np.arange(ny)
# array([0, 1, 2])
```

are just the indices for the "y-axis", the first dimension of `data`. And

```
y_idx = np.arange(ny)[:,np.newaxis]
# array([[0],
#        [1],
#        [2]])
```

adds a [new axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to this array (after the existing axis) and effectively transposes it. When you now use this array in an indexing expression together with the `subindex` array, the former gets [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to the shape of the latter. So `y_idx` becomes effectively:

```
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

And now for each pair of `y_idx` and `subindex` you look up an element in the `data` array.

[Here you can find out more about "fancy indexing"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial)

Comment: Ah great, I hadn't encountered broadcasting indices before. This works very well for me with 3D and 4D arrays for e.g.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to do two things:

- Find all indices into the data array and
- Translate the column indices according to some other array, subindex.

The code below therefore generates indices for all array positions (using `np.indices`), and reshapes it to `(..., 2)` -- a 2-D list of coordinates representing each position in the array.  For each coordinate, `(i, j)`, we then translate the column coordinate `j` using the subindex array provided, and then use that translated index as the new column index.

With numpy, it is not necessary to do that in a for-loop--we can simply pass in all the indices at once:

```
i, j = np.indices(data.shape).reshape((-1, 2)).T
data[i, subindex[i, j]]
```

Comment: @Stonz2 You are right of course.  I was in a rush earlier and wanted to provide a hint for exploration.  I've now updated the answer to reflect what's happening.

Comment: Thanks that works well. I found that `.reshape((2,-1))` worked for me.