# 2D indexing of scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (1000, 100))

# prob better way to do this
d = np.random.random((1000,1000))
d[d < 0.99] = 0
y = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(d)
```

What I would like to do is to create a new matrix `z` containing the values of `y` at the indices in `x`.

ie [0, 0] of z should contain the y[0, x[0, 0]]

[0, 1] of z should contain the y[0, x[0, 1]]

```
%time for i in range(1000): x[i, y[i]].todense()
~247ms
%time for i in range(1000): np.take(x[i].todense(), y[i])
~150ms
```

both of the above work, but I am looking for a faster method- this is currently the bottleneck on my code.

Please assume that representing the whole scipy.sparse matrix as dense isn't feasible.

edit:
`%time z = np.vstack([q.todense()[0, p] for q, p in zip(x, y)])`

is ~110ms

Comment: your use of variables in time tests doesn't match the rest.  Indexing sparse matrix is inherently slow.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to use an appropriately shaped broadcasting index, as outlined here: [How to generate multi-dimensional 2D numpy index using a sub-index for one dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898685/how-to-generate-multi-dimensional-2d-numpy-index-using-a-sub-index-for-one-dimen)
(answer deserves more upvotes)!

```
%time res = y[np.arange(0, 1000).reshape((-1, 1)), x].todense()
```